# confirm() в yii2 выполняет действие если нажать отмена

Tags: php, yii2

Я повесил на кнопку `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-group-justified" id="save" onclick="confirm('Вы уверены что хотите сохранить?')">Сохранить</button>`

Обработчик `confirm()`

Он работает, окошко всплывает, но действие выполняется даже если нажать кнопку отменить.

Что я делаю не так? Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onclick="if(!confirm('Вы уверены что хотите сохранить?')) return false;"
```

или

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-group-justified" id="save" 
onclick="if(confirm('Вы уверены что хотите сохранить?')) 
this.form.submit()">Сохранить</button>
```

кнопка уже не submit, а button

Comment: Мне первый вариант подходит как надо . Спасибо!